# Delete Relationship with JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have two JPA entities, lets call them A and B.

An A has a ManyToMany Relation to B.

```
@Entity
class A {    
    @ManyToMany
    List<B> bobjects;
}

@Entity
class B {    
    String id;
}
```

I now need to remove a number of B objects from the List in an A object, retaining the B Object.

Naively, I'd iterate over the list, remove the ones I want to remove, and save A again. But this is too slow, the list can become quite long.

I want to remove via JPQL by supplying a list of IDs, but I don't know how to remove the relationship only, I can remove the B objects, but I want to keep them.

This is how far I've gotten.

```
DELETE FROM A a.bobjects WHERE a.bobjects IN :bIds
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If not I'll use an SQL Query to delete it, but would be interesting if this is possible.

Comment: I have the feeling, it is not supported by the JPA spec, but some implementations may do.

Comment: You are missing the `@ManyToMany` annotation on Class B, and you are also missing the `mappedBy` attribute which would tell us whether A owns B or vice-versa (and this information is probably necessary to attempt an answer to your question).